# How to search for SharePoint file using dash separated string?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

i'm trying to find a SharePoint file using Microsoft graph search API but it went wrong whenever i search using dash separated string as following

`var uri =new Uri(string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{0}/drive/root/search(q='{1}')", baseSiteId, "766bf0c3-e83f-4913-8a74-eb500acd208a-test.xlsx"));`

i expected to get the file with this name which i'm sure that it exists but i get no files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need search in parent drive if your file not in root drive(Shared Documents).

Test demo:

/sites/siteid/drives/driveid/root/search(q='Questionnaire-Lee Li.docx')

[image]

Comment: so if the file is not in the root drive i will have to search in the drive contains it